# APM - How to healthcheck a background program?

Tags: linux, algorithm, monitoring, health-monitoring, apm

We have,

two GoLang microservices(http server)

&

one GoLang background program(running infinite loop).

---

Within micro-service, we have added diagnostic endpoint point(http port), to provide health-check of service. Grafana monitoring tool talks to this diagnostoc end point.

For background program,

How to diagnose health-check(up or down) of backend program? application healthcheck monitoring

Comment: What about https://github.com/docker/go-healthcheck? Does this monitor healthcheck of both http service & backend program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a small HTTP server in the background program, which responds to health-check requests.

When you get a request, you can verify a state which is updated in the infinite loop (it actually depends on your custom logic).

This way you can inspect the health of your program in grafana as well (consistency).

Comment: Is there.another way to monitor an application without http end point? I know this http server approach, but we have business constraints to use heavy backend framework to add a simple http endpoint, which we are reluctant to do, from timeline aspect. I understand your point on consistency.

Comment: Sure, you can launch a HTTP request from your backend service to a healthcheck infrastructure/REST API (each time you run a cycle, for example). Another idea would be to update an environment variable (with some healthcheck status / timestamp), and have another service which would read it

Comment: Our health infrastruture has grafana. Can grafana receives these http requests, from background program? if yes, please share some reference...

Comment: It depends on which metric system you use. If you use Graphite, then yes, you can make a HTTP call to graphite, link Grafana to it and you'll be able to see the health status. If you use Prometheus, you need to set up a push gateway

Comment: Let me know which metric you use (maybe there are better options)

Comment: We just want to know, if the backend program is up or down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227289/discussion-between-cosmin-ioni-and-overexchange).